# Generics and objects conversion in C#

Tags: c#, generics, object, types, type-conversion

I have a class which is handling objects same way.
It's like:

```
class Handler<T>{
    private T _obj;
    public T obj{
        get{
            ...//do sth
            return _obj;
        }
        set{
            ...//do sth
            _obj = value;
        }
    }
    ... // some other properties, no T anymore
}
```

There are large amount of code working on `Handler` objects, ignoring type. I mean, type `T` is not for them, there are setting other fields.
There are containers with `Handler<>` and so on.

At the end I need to return Handler with correct type.

I wanted to use `Handler<object>`, but there is no way I know to convert it to `Handler<SomeClass>`.

How can I handle situtations like this?

Comment: Please show the code in question.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092393/value-of-type-t-cannot-be-converted-to

Comment: I see not question mark, what are you asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you make a base class for `Handler<T>`, which will contain all non-generic code?

```
class HandlerBase
{
   // some other properties
}

class Handler<T> : HandlerBase
{
    public T obj { ... }
}
```

If your "large amount of code" ignores `T`, than let it work with `HandlerBase`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an IHandler interface.

```
IHandler<SomeClass> h1 = new Handler<SomeClass>();
IHandler<Object> h2 = h1;
```

This will work !
More info on [Covariance on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)