# C# Cast class with variable type parameter. Code snippet explains it

Tags: c#, type-conversion, type-parameter

Why doesn't this work and how do I make it work? In this case M directly implements IMessage and I get a **InvalidCastException**.

```
public void Subscribe<M>(IMessageListener<M> listener) where M : IMessage
{
    IMessageListener<IMessage> l = (IMessageListener<IMessage>)listener;
}
```

Shouldn't casting `IMessageListener<M>` to `IMessageListener<IMessage>` work when `M` implements `IMessage`?

Sorry for the bad title, didn't know how to describe it.

//EDIT
The IMessageListener class looks like this:

```
public interface IMessageListener<M> where M : IMessage
{
    void ProcessMessage(M message);
}
```

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that misleading answer - I just posted it based on something I read up sometime back. Hope this answer helps you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166133

Comment: Why do you need to cast it? Just use it as an `IMessageListener<IMessage>` – call `listener.ProcessMessage(message)` later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, it shouldn't work.

```
public class MessageA : IMessage
{
    public int SpecificAField;
}

public class MessageB : IMessage {}

public class MessageAListener : IMessageListener<MessageA>
{
    public void ProcessMessage(MessageA message)
    {
        messageA.SpecificAField = 3;
    }
}
```

If the compiler were to let `Subscribe<MessageA>`? cast the `MessageAListener` to `IMessageListener<IMessage>`, then you could pass it a `MessageB`.

Then the `MessageAListener` would try to set `SpecificAField` on the `MessageB`, and it doesn't have one.

---

This doesn't work because `IMessageListener<T>` is *contravariant* on `T` - it references `T` solely as an *input*. Thus you can cast an `IMessageListener<IMessage>` to an `IMessageListener<MessageA>` because it will happily accept a `MessageA` as an *input* in place of an `IMessage`.

The cast you want to perform would require `IMessageListener<T>` to be *covariant* on `T` - it would have to reference `T` solely as an *output*. You could then cast an `IMessageListener<MessageA>` to an `IMessageListener<IMessage>` as the true return type, `MessageA`, can be converted to the expected return type, `IMessage`.

Comment: Ok, I get that. My problem is, that I have a Dictionary with a Type as key and a list of instances of the type as the value, that implements IMessage. How would I implement that then?

Comment: Do you know where I could read more about covariance? Its totally new to me

Comment: @Zoidy Mixing generics and type objects is usually a mistake. Generics handle different types at compile time; type objects handle different types at run time. Eric Lippert has a good series on covariance starting [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx).