# How to access base-class member using a generic-type constrained to interface?

Tags: c#, interface, member, base-class, interface-implementation

In my base-class (`Entity`) I have implemented a method (`GetEntity`) defined by my interface (`IEntity`). That method works on a generic type (`TEntity`) constrained to the interface type. In said method, I would like to take the generic type and cast it as a base-class type to access a member (`ParentKeyFields`) defined in the base-class. Here is the code:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    TEntity GetEntity<TEntity>(string identifier) where TEntity : IEntity;
}

public class Entity : IEntity
{
    private readonly IDataProvider DataProvider;
    private readonly IUserContext UserContext;

    public List<string> ParentKeyFields { get; set; }

    public Entity(IDataProvider dataProvider, IUserContext userContext)
    {
        // ...

        ParentKeyFields = new List<string>();
    }

    public TEntity GetEntity<TEntity>(string identifier) where TEntity : IEntity
    {
        // Approach #1:
        TEntity result = default(TEntity);
        List<string> test = ((Entity)result).ParentKeyFields;
        // This gives me an error saying: "Cannot conver type 'TEntity' to 'Entity'".

        // Approach #2:
        Entity result = (TEntity) new Entity(DataProvider, UserContext);
        // This gives me an error saying: "Cannot convert type 'Entity' to 'TEntity'.
        List<string> test = result.ParentKeyFields;
        return result;
        // This gives me an error saying: "Cannot implictly convert type 'Entity' to 'TEntity'".
    }
}
```

I am unable to access the member (`ParentKeyFields`). I've tried casting on object creation and when accessing the member. Neither approach will compile.

I want to access the different values that may be defined in that member for different derived types:

```
class Company : Entity
{
    public Company(IDataProvider dataProvider, IUserContext userContext) : base(dataProvider, userContext)
    {
    }
}

public class Employee : Entity
{
    public Employee(IDataProvider dataProvider, IUserContext userContext) : base(dataProvider, userContext)
    {
        ParentKeyFields.Add("co");
    }
}

public class EIns : Entity
{
    public EIns(IDataProvider dataProvider, IUserContext userContext) : base(dataProvider, userContext)
    {
        ParentKeyFields.Add("co");
        ParentKeyFields.Add("id");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Entity test = system.GetEntity<Employee>("foobar");
    }
}
```

I am new to interfaces and how they are implemented, so my naivety may be steering me in the wrong direction. How may I reconstruct my code to make this work?

Comment: If `ParentKeyFields` is required for an entity, add it to `IEntity`.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092393/value-of-type-t-cannot-be-converted-to) explains why you can't cast to base class and shows how to do it via `(object)` cast. Note that most likely you should not be doing it and think on some better approach instead (i.e. as @EdPlunkett suggested move field to the interface).

Comment: Is it semantically okay to move the member to the interface even if it is only used within the classes themselves and never by any other consuming code?

Comment: @MaxJacob At its worst, IMO that’s a lot less awful than casting to object and then to Entity.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Fair enough. Thank you for the advice!