# Cant convert Generic<string> to Generic<TArg> even though i am trying to do this after checking wether Generic<string>is assignable to Generic<TArg>

Tags: c#, .net-core

Pretty much the title. I have this code:

```cs
if (typeof(Option<string>).IsAssignableTo(typeof(Option<E>)))
{
  return new Result<T, E>(None<T>(), (Option<E>)result.GetErr());
}
```

within this implicit conversion operator:

```cs
public static implicit operator Result<T, E>(ResultT<T> result)
{
  Debug.Assert(result.IsValid());
  if (result.IsOk())
  {
    return new Result<T, E>(result.GetOk(), None<E>());
  }
  else
  {
    if (typeof(E).IsAssignableTo(typeof(Exception)))
    {
      return new Result<T, E>(None<T>(), ((E)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(E), new object[] { result.GetErr().DefaultValue("") })!).Some());
    }
/* Begin of the 1. Code Snippet */
    else if (typeof(Option<string>).IsAssignableTo(typeof(Option<E>)))
    {
      return new Result<T, E>(None<T>(), (Option<E>)result.GetErr()); /*Result_T.GetErr() always returns Option<string>*/
/* End of 1. Code Snippet */
    }
  } 
}
```

The goal of my first snippet is basically to convert the `Result_T<T>` to a `Result<T, string>`

The constructor of `Result<T, E>` expects the following:

```cs
private Result(Option<T> OkVal, Option<E> ErrVal)
{
  value = OkVal;
  error = ErrVal;
}
```

(I am of course checking wether the struct is valid)

However even though `Option<string>` is in theory assigable to `Option<E>`, the compiler prevents it.

(`CS0030    Cannot convert type 'Toolkit.Option<string>' to 'Toolkit.Option<E>'`)

Whats the reason behind this, and how can I make this work?

Minimal reproducible Example

```cs
// this example is VERY minimal. almost everything unused or unnessesary was stripped

/// <summary>
/// Option<T>`s job in my program is to wrap a value. and track its state (SOME or NONE). Basically a more feature-rich version of the native nullable<T>. In this example it only wraps it.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"> The type </typeparam>
public struct Option<T>
{
  public static Option<T> None => default;
  public static Option<T> Some(T value) => new Option<T>(value);
  private readonly T _value;

  private Option(T val)
  {
    _value = val;
  }
  public T Unwrap()
  {
    return _value;
  }

}
/// <summary>
/// Holds either the Result of type T, or a string describing the error
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public struct Result_T<T>
{
  // pardon these variable names, they where suggested by intellisense. Also here too no proper state tracking
  private readonly Option<string> _err;
  public static Result_T<T> Err(string error) => new Result_T<T>(Option<T>.None, Option<string>.Some(error), true);
  private Result_T(Option<T> res, Option<string> err, bool state)
  {
    _err = err;
  }
  public Option<string> GetErr() => _err;

}
/// <summary>
/// holds either a result of type T, or an error of type E
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="E"></typeparam>
public struct Result<T, E>
{
  private Option<E> _err;
  private Result(Option<T> val, Option<E> err)
  {
    _err= err;
  }
  public static implicit operator Result<T, E>(Result_T<T> result)
  {
   if (typeof(Option<string>).IsAssignableTo(typeof(Option<E>)))
    {
      return new Result<T, E>(Option<T>.None, (Option<E>)result.GetErr());
    }
    throw new Exception(" This Exception is just to make the 'not all codepaths return a value' error go away");
  }
  public E GetErr()
  {
    return _err.Unwrap();
  }
}
internal class Program
{
  private static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(((Result<int, string>)Result_T<int>.Err("some error")).GetErr());
  }
}
```

Also, I have decided to refactor my code in a way that this conversion is not needed anymore, but I would still be curious about your opinions on this.

Comment: What is `Option<T>`?  Can you share a [mcve] showing (possibly simplified) code demonstrating the error that we could copy into a standalone console app, compile and run?

Comment: But probably related: [Value of type 'T' cannot be converted to](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4092393).

Comment: The compiler doesn't infer type constraints from runtime calls to `Type.IsAssignableTo()`

Comment: What type is result in your first example?  What does GetErr return?

Comment: @dragon I have edited the second example to make it more clear where my 1. code snippet is located inside it. Also I fixed my first comment

Comment: @dbc I added a *VERY* minimal example

Comment: Your code cannot work that way, you cannot cast from string to E if there is no cnstraint on E, making them related.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't infer type constraints from runtime calls to `Type.IsAssignableTo()`.

Furthermore, it has to compile every branch of your method, even the ones which will not be taken (as a result of runtime conditionals), and it has to do so based only on the type constraints.  Then the JIT will compile the generic to only a single machine code implementation covering all reference types.

Generics are not templates -- there's no compilation choices (overload resolution, dead code removal) being redone after the actual type parameters are known.

Comment: So what should I do instead? Could I possibly overload the implicit operator with a second version that somehow constrains E to be a string? How?